# cancelPeripheralConnection invokes didFailToConnectPeripheral

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I'm writing the app which uses `CoreBluetooth` framework. Everything is fine except one thing. According to Apple documentation for [CBCentralManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/cancelPeripheralConnection:), calling `cancelPeripheralConnection:` method causes invoking of `centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:` delegate method, but in my case `centralManager:didFailToConnectPeripheral:error:` is invoked. Any clues why is that?

Thanks for every help.

**Edit**

I'm not connected to peripheral, but I have pending connection. To be specific, I call `connectPeripheral:` method and when app is waiting for connection, user taps "Cancel" button. Then, I call `cancelPeripheralConneciton:` and later I have situation described above. The error I get has domain `CBErrorDomain` and description `Unknown error`.

Comment: Have you actually connected to the peripheral or do you have a pending connection?  Do you get an error?

Comment: I would say it is a documentation error. If you aren't actually connected to the peripheral then it makes sense that `didFailToConnectPeripheral` is called. You didn't disconnect because you never connected.